# Any subset of totally ordered set X is totally ordered for the restriction of the order on X

Tags: algebra, set-theory

I do understand every subset of a totally ordered set must be a total order as each a, b in the totally ordered set follows either aRb or bRa.
I don’t understand what the phrase “for the restriction of the order on X” means? Can anyone explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An *order* in a set `X` is a *relation* between elements of `X`, this is, a subset `R` of the Cartesian product `X × X` that satisfies the axioms of order (or total order, etc.).

If `Y` is a subset of `X`, the *restriction to* `Y` of the order on `X` is the intersection `R ∩ Y×Y` of the relation `R` with the subset `Y×Y ⊆ X×X`.

In other words, is the same order, but restricted to the subset `Y`.